# Vue-Apollo - can't access result of query

Tags: vue.js, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

i can't access the result object of my apollo query. I want to use the result to show it in a plot.ly graph.

```
const apolloClient = new Apollo.lib.ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: Apollo.lib.createNetworkInterface({
    uri: '{% url 'graphql' %}',
    transportBatching: true,
  }),
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo.ApolloProvider({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})

const VALUE_QUERY = Apollo.gql`
query {
  allSensordata {
    id
    value
  }
}
`
```

This is just the Vue Component for using with plot.ly.

```
//VueJS Component
Vue.component("reactive-chart", {
  props: ["chart"],
  template: '<div :ref="chart.uuid" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>',
  mounted() {
    Plotly.plot(this.$refs[this.chart.uuid], this.chart.traces, this.chart.layout);
  },
  watch: {
    chart: {
      handler: function() {
        Plotly.react(
          this.$refs[this.chart.uuid],
          this.chart.traces,
          this.chart.layout
        );
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the Vue Main Code where i want to bring the apollo graphql result to the graph.

```
//VueJS Main App
var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: "#app",
  // Apollo GraphQL
  apolloProvider,
  apollo: {
    allSensordata: {
      query: VALUE_QUERY,
      loadingKey:'loading',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: 0,
      chart: {
        uuid: "123",
        traces: [
          {
            y: [1,2,3,4,3,2,1], //Here should be: this.allSensordata.value
            line: {
              color: "#5e9e7e",
              width: 4,
              shape: "line"
            }
          }
        ],
        layout: {}
      }
    };
  },
});
```

I think i didn't get the object structure of the Apollo-module. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add allSensordata to your data field. If I remember correctly, after executing your query you should be able to access the object with this.allSensordata.allSensordata.value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to add it to the data field, but i get the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: allSensordata is not defined'. Do you have any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Okay, have you tried to inspect the object by console.log()? I think you have to implement it to the mounted() function. Just to make sure the structure is correct. At that point the data should be available.

Comment: Unfortunately the console logs: 'undefined'. I used   mounted(){
    console.log(this.allSensordata)
  },

Comment: But when i examine console.log(this) i can find an object '_data', with an object 'allSensordata'. There all my data are stored. So the query was successfull and the data is available. I have to learn how to call this '_data' object.

Comment: Please try it with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sadbn5k3/

Comment: Thank you! Now the console.log(data) of the result function prints the Sensordata. The log of the mounted log is still null.

Comment: To store the result of your query to a local variable just change console.log() of the result function to this.allSensordata = data.allSensordata.value;

Comment: Sorry, but i can't get the data out of the apollo object. I tried as you described. But there seems to be like a barrier between the apollo object and the environment. Is it because i use apollo-client-browser (1.9.0)? Should i try to build my project with new apollo-client (2.x)? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Give it a try, maybe it will solve your problem. Could you please tell me the structure of the object you've got with console.log(data)?

Comment: The structure is as follows: {allSensordata: Array(10), Symbol(id): "ROOT_QUERY"}
allSensordata
:
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
Symbol(id)
:
"ROOT_QUERY"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Thanks. That means you have to change my advice to this.allSensordata = data.allSensordata. This will assign an array to your local variable (this.allSensordata). To access an item in this array, you have to write something like this: this.allSensordata[index]. The index is an integer, in your case between 0 and 9 because your Array has 10 items.

Comment: To hopefully answer your inital question I've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sadbn5k3/10/ ... because you wanted to assign the values to this.chart.traces[0].y